# How the value of the tj operator is generated in a pdf document (justified text)

Tags: pdf, text, pdf-generation, right-justified, pdftextstream

I can't understand and find how the value of the tj operator is generated??

Here I paste result before and after changes in the display of the text (on the second block I changed the position Left-Justice and then again comeback to Centered)

I think pdf use some of prng, but what kind of, I can't find

HElp please

> [(\003\024\027\005\003\030\036\b)**-114.267**(\003\006\007\024\036\b)-113.297(\026\002\024\003\032\020\b)**-113.337**(\b)**-111.574**(#\024\002\f\005\002\021\003\007\004\f\005\b)**-117.089**(\003\006\002\003\b)**-114.08**

---

> [(\003\024\027\005\003\030\036\b)**-114.366**(\003\006\007\024\036\b)-113.297(\026\002\024\003\032\020\b)**-113.327**(\b)**-111.693**(#\024\002\f\005\002\021\003\007\004\f\005\b)**-116.98**(\003\006\002\003\b)**-114.188**

Comment: The excepts you show are not relevant for justification. Please take a look at the surrounding instructions.

Comment: But what it show? 
this part is changed, i think that's justification.
instructions you mean ios32000-2008?

Comment: No. Your excerpts are from PDF content streams which are sequences of instructions. The **TJ** operator with its arguments is an instruction. There are other instructions in the content stream, too. Look at differences in them.

Comment: What the specification? @mlk

Comment: Can you give the link

Comment: http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf

Comment: I can find instruction some more http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf

Comment: But i can't find how generated TJ values; i'm think that this value depends by operators Tm @mkl

Comment: @mkl you my last hope to understand how generated this value

Comment: The **Tm** operator is one option indeed. It sets the text matrix which includes the current position for text commands. There are other instructions, too, though, which manipulate that position.

Comment: Can you help me? what the other instructions??
I can't understand. I burn down already (

Comment: Can you help me?  @mkl

Comment: I'll try and write an answer. But I'm afraid you won't be completely happy about it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the PDF format does not explicitly support text justification. PDF does not even know text column definitions to justify text in!

All the PDF format supports is

- setting or changing the text matrix (and text line matrix), scaling, character and word spacing explicitly and
- drawing text pieces which implicitly changes the text matrix.

Thus, if a PDF processor changes the *justification of a line of text*, it actually first has to have determined

- which text pieces belong together and form that *line of text*;

  text pieces can be given as arguments of the **Tj** or **TJ** instructions (or more seldom the **"** or **'** instructions); in simple cases the whole *line* is drawn using a single instruction but you cannot count on that in general; and
- what the left and right borders of the text column are to justify between;

  e.g. these borders might be standard values assumed by the processor for certain page formats or derived from the current clip path.

Having determined these data, the procedure differs for different kinds of justification:

- *left justification* - position the text matrix at the left text column border at the height of the line and simple let the text drawing instructions follow;
- *right justification* - calculate the width of the drawn line using the current font, position the text matrix at the right text column border minus that width at the height of the line, and let the text drawing instructions follow;
- *center justification* - calculate the width of the drawn line using the current font, position the text matrix at the middle of the text column minus half that width at the height of the line, and let the text drawing instructions follow;
- *full justification* - calculate the width of the drawn line using the current font, set the character spacing and word spacing (using the **Tc** and **Tw** instructions, probably with a tweak of the **Tz** horizontal scaling) to use up the difference between that width and the text column width, position the text matrix at the left text column border at the height of the line, and let the text drawing instructions follow;

  or calculate the width of the drawn line using the current font, change the text drawing instructions to use up the difference between that width and the text column width (e.g. using the numeric **TJ** array argument values), position the text matrix at the left text column border at the height of the line, and let the changed text drawing instructions follow;

  or even apply a combination of these methods.

(The changes applied when doing a full justification - character spacing, word spacing, changes of text drawing instructions - obviously additionally are undone when later again changing to another type of justification...)

Positioning the text matrix can happen using the **Tm**, **Td**, **TD**, and **T*** instructions.

*By the way, the positioning and scaling of the text also is influenced by the current transformation matrix. Thus, **cm** instructions can also be used for justification. But this is less likely than the use of the instructions mentioned above...*

---

Unfortunately you merely supplied an excerpt from the array argument of a **TJ** instruction before and after such a justification job. One sees that the numeric elements of that array change very slightly. Whether this actually is the justification itself (as per the second option of the *full justification* above) or merely some computational inaccuracy cannot be told without the context.